# I added a void function to my program that takes no parameters and now my program only return a blank terminal when I run it

Tags: c++

I'm doing a programming project that requires me to use void functions to display output. I decide to add the void function after I wrote most of my program. After I added it, the program runs but the program seems to be stuck. Like it will run, but nothing but the blank console will appear. No errors are returned. I tried to delete the void function and run it again, but the same thing is still happening.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const float FT_TO_M = 0.3048;

double ConvertMetersToFeet(double meters);

double ConvertFeetToMeters(double feet);

double RectangleFeet(double length, double width);

double RectangleMeters(double length, double width);

void ShowInstructions( );

bool run = true;
int menu(int choice);

int main(){

    char go;

    do{ 

        int ans;
        int choice = menu(ans);

        ShowInstructions();

        switch(choice){
            case 1:{
                run = true;
                double MetersEntered;
                cout << "Enter the number of meters that you want to be  converted : ";
                cin >> MetersEntered;
                double FeetOut = ConvertMetersToFeet(MetersEntered);
                cout << "Here's the converted amount in feet: " << FeetOut << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                run = true;
                double FeetEntered;
                cout << "Enter the number of feet that you want to be converted : ";
                cin >> FeetEntered;
                double MetersOut = ConvertFeetToMeters(FeetEntered);
                cout << "Here's the converted amount in meters: " << MetersOut << endl;
                break;
            }    
            case 3:{
                run = true;
                break;
            }    
            case 4:{
                run = true;
                break;
            }
            case 5:
                run = false;
                break;
        }

        cout << "If you want to run the program again type y or Y. Any other key will end the program ";
        cin >> go;

    }while(run == true && (go == 'y' || go == 'Y'));

    return 0;
}

int menu(int choice){
        cin >> choice;
        return choice;
}

double ConvertMetersToFeet(double meters){

    double feet = meters / FT_TO_M;

    return feet;
}

double ConvertFeetToMeters(double feet){

    double meters = feet * FT_TO_M;

    return meters;
}

double RectangleFeet(double length, double width){

    double area = ConvertMetersToFeet(length) * ConvertMetersToFeet(width);

    return area;
}

double RectangleMeters(double length, double width){
    double area = (length * FT_TO_M) * (width * FT_TO_M);

    return area;
}

void ShowInstructions( ){
    cout << "English-Metric Junior\n\n"
    "1) Convert from meters to feet\n\n"
    "2) Convert from feet to meters\n\n"
    "3) Compute the area of a rectangle in square feet given length and width in meters\n\n"
    "4) Compute the area of a rectangle in square meters given the length and width in feet\n\n"
    "5) Quit the Program\n\n"
    "Please enter a number (1-5) -> ";
}
```

I also want my do-while loop to stop running when the user enters 5, but before the program completely stopped running it would keep going. That's relatively unimportant. I just want the program to run. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should move your cin after the  ShowInstructions(); function call:

```
   ShowInstructions();
   int choice = menu(ans);
```

then your case 5 should be:

```
case 5:
            run = false;  // you dont really require this
            return 0;    // to terminate program
```

also recommended to add default case:

```
default:break;
```

you can optimize while loop by:

```
 while(run && (go == 'y' || go == 'Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see in your void function is that the strings aren't really concatenated. You can either leave them all as one long string or put << at the end of each line to tell cout that there is more coming. c++ might also allow concatenation by simply using + to add them all together.

Comment: I've had that same string in multiple places in the program and it was never a problem, but I did add << as you said. It made no difference. The terminal is still blank.